# Add prefix to graphite micrometer event in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, graphite, micrometer

I am using `spring-boot 2` with `graphite`. I want to add a prefix to all my metrics.

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistry graphiteRegistsry() {
    return new GraphiteMeterRegistry(
           GraphiteConfig.DEFAULT, Clock.SYSTEM,
           (id, convention) -> "prefix." + 
           HierarchicalNameMapper.DEFAULT.toHierarchicalName(id,convention));
}
```

If I use this code this is actually add prefix, But also create some metrics without the prefix. It seems that their is almost all the  metrics is duplicate.

How can I add this prefix? and that all the metrics that goes to graphite from this app will contains the prefix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you can add a common tag using `MeterRegistryCustomizer`:

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {
  @Bean
  public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> commonTags() {
    return r -> r.config().commonTags("commonTag", "somePrefix");
  }
}
```

Second, extend your application properties converting this tag to prefix:

```
management.metrics.export.graphite.tags-as-prefix=commonTag
```

Please have a look at the detailed explanation [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/348)

Comment: I tried this, I dont know what I did wrong last time

Comment: Will this work for statsd configuration?
I'm having the following config for my springboot app.
 
statsd:
        host: "localhost"
        port: 8125
        enabled: true
        prefix: ${spring.application.name}